Incrementally build up `express`'s `res.locals` type across multiple middlewares
Consider the following:
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

type MyRequestHandler<T extends express.Locals> = express.RequestHandler<
  unknown,
  unknown,
  unknown,
  unknown,
  T
>;

const middleware1: MyRequestHandler<{ a: number }> = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.a = 3;
  next();
};

const middleware2: MyRequestHandler<{ b: number }> = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.b = 4;
  next();
};

app.get('/', middleware1, middleware2, (req, res) => {
  const a = res.locals.a;
  const b = res.locals.b;
  console.log(a, b);
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

My goal is for the TypeScript compiler to infer that middleware1 added a to locals, and middleware2 added b to locals.
Right now, TypeScript doesn't allow adding middleware2 the way I did because it doesn't extends middleware1, which is true.
Is there a way to make MyRequestHandler generic over the Locals parameter of RequestHandler?
Is there other way to make this work?

Your running into a common issue when working with express.locals and trying to incrementally build up the res.locals type across multiple middlewares. By default Express doesnt have built in support for "merging" res.locals types across middleware. BUT - you can define a custom TypedRequestHandler that acummulates the type of res.locals through an intersection type (&) across all middleware.
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

type MyRequestHandler<T extends Record<string, any>> = express.RequestHandler<
  unknown,
  unknown,
  unknown,
  unknown,
  T
>;

const middleware1: MyRequestHandler<{ a: number }> = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.a = 3;
  next();
};

// Middleware 2: Adds 'b' to locals
const middleware2: MyRequestHandler<{ b: number }> = (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.b = 4;
  next();
};

app.get(
  '/',
  middleware1,
  middleware2,
  ((req, res: express.Response<{ a: number } & { b: number }>, next) => {
    const a = res.locals.a;
    const b = res.locals.b;
    console.log(a, b);
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }) as express.RequestHandler
);


Exactly! The thing is, it's not DRY to specify { a: number } & { b: number } for the res, I want TypeScript to infer it.
